# k3s with skaffold: container can't be pulled

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry, k3s, skaffold

I'm creating a micro-service API I want to run on a local raspberry k3s cluster.

The aim is to use skaffold to deploy during development.

The problem I have is everytime I use `skaffold dev` I have the same error :

```
deployment/epos-auth-deploy: container epos-auth is waiting to start: 192.168.1.10:8080/epos_auth:05ea8c1@sha256:4e7f7c7224ce1ec4831627782ed696dee68b66929b5641e9fc6cfbfc4d2e82da can't be pulled
```

I've tried to setup a local docker registry which is defined with this docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  registry:
    image: registry:latest
    volumes:
      - ./registry-data:/var/lib/registry
    networks:
      - registry-ui-net

  ui:
    image: joxit/docker-registry-ui:static
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - REGISTRY_TITLE=Docker Registry
      - REGISTRY_URL=http://registry:5000
    depends_on:
      - registry
    networks:
      - registry-ui-net

networks:
  registry-ui-net:
```

It's working on `http://192.168.1.10:8080` on my local network.

It seems ok when it builds and pushes the image.

[image: The image is visible in the repository]

I also have set **/etc/docker/daemon.json** on my local computer

```
{
        "insecure-registries": ["192.168.1.10:8080"],
        "registry-mirrors": ["http://192.168.1.10:8080"]
}
```

I've set the **/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml** on all the nodes:

```
mirrors:
  docker.io:
    endpoint:
      - "http://192.168.1.10:8080"
```

**skaffold.yaml** looks like this :

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: epos-skaffold
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/skaffold/*
build:
  local:
    useBuildkit: true
  artifacts:
    - image: epos_auth
      context: epos-auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

And **./infra/k8s/skaffold/epos-auth-deploy.yaml** looks like this :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: epos-auth-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: epos-auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: epos-auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: epos-auth
          image: epos_auth
          env:
            - name: NATS_URL
              value: http://nats-srv:4222
            - name: NATS_CLUSTER_ID
              value: epos
            - name: NATS_CLIENT_ID
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef: 
                  name: jwt-keys
                  key: key
            - name: JWT_PRIVATE_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef: 
                  name: jwt-keys
                  key: private_key
            - name: JWT_PUBLIC_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef: 
                  name: jwt-keys
                  key: public_key
            - name: MONGO_URI
              value: mongodb://mongodb-srv:27017/auth-service
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: epos-auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: epos-auth
  ports:
    - name: epos-auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

I did

```
skaffold config set default-repo 192.168.1.10:8080

skaffold config set insecure-registries 192.168.1.10:8080
```

I really don't know what's wrong with this.

Do you have any clue please ?

Comment: Hello, I think you should post your edited (answer part) as the actual answer to this question and accept it. This would make it inherently more visible to the other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I installed docker-ce on the master node. Then I created the master node with `--docker` parameter in the command.
- When I created the k3s node, I defined a context. I forgot to replace `default` context in `~/.skaffold/config`

Answer (score 0):

Please change the `docker.io` reference as it is confusing;

```
mirrors:
  docker.io:
    endpoint:
      - "http://192.168.1.10:8080"
```

And use the `image` with the full registry path just like:
`registry.local:5000/epos_auth`

https://devopsspiral.com/articles/k8s/k3d-skaffold/

Comment: The problem does not come from this.

Comment: The endpoint is 192.168.1.10:8080. I've corrected this problem. It was the context not correctly set in `.skaffold/config`. Now my last problem I hope is to build arm64 docker images on amd64 computer to push them in the registry and pull them on the nodes.